# how can I document multidimensional object?

Tags: object, documentation, gulp, jsdoc

I'm using the gulp plugin for http://documentation.js.org/ which generates the whole index file so that it's easy to read documentation for my project.

My question is, let's say I have an object like so:

```
/**
 * a
 * @namespace
 */

var a = {

    /**
     * b
     * @namespace a.b
     */

    b : {

        /**
         * c
         * @namespace a.b.c
         */

        c : function() {

        }
    }
};
```

I was hoping to see that the sidebar would have a multi indented list, instead of displaying the items like so:

```
A
    B
        C
```

It displays them like so:

```
A
    B
C
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you might be interested in nested objects documentation:

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the memberof directive you can easily specify the namespace and linkage between sub modules/tags

```
/**
 * @name a
 * @module
 */

var a = {

    /**
     * @name b
     * @memberof a
     * @module
     */

    b : {

        /**
         * @name c
         * @memberof b
         */

        c : function() {

        }
    }
};
```